# I don't want to step out to the newline after using std::cin

Tags: c++, xcode, newline, cin

I'm writing a simple name with some terminal outline. But when I get an input with using `cin`, my border messes up. Is there any way to prevent the newline after entering the input via using `cin`?

I am using XCode 4.

Comment: What do you mean by prevent newline?

Comment: For example, when I use cin >> myInput; , After entering my input it jumps to new line. it does the same thing with endline after entering my input, dont want it to happen.

Comment: You need not press enter after the input then.. just give a space after the input and continue with next input. `cin` terminates the input, after it encounters a whitespace.

Comment: Except that normally `cin` instruction end when a newline, or a EOF is detected. Try sending a EOF via the keyboard (in Linux it's `ctrl+d`), it should stay in the same line.

Answer (score 2):

If you want complete control over the terminal display, you'll probably need to use the `curses` library, or something similar (`ncurses` on GNU systems, for example).  This allows you to control the display of characters and suppress the automatic echoing of characters during input, and therefore there will not be any newline.  But, you won't be using `stdin::cin` any more, either.

Using `std::cin` means that you will have to accept that your program doesn't see any of the data until the newline is typed, and that the terminal will often scroll at that point.  (Not always; if the current line is near the top of the screen, then there won't be scrolling.)